# Why cannot I get `where` to work in Hspec

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, hspec

I'm struggling with the semantics of `where` within `do` blocks, specifically with `Test.Hspec`.  The following works:

```
module ExampleSpec where

import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck

spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "foo" $ do
        let
            f = id
            in
                it "id" $ property $
                    \x -> f x `shouldBe` (x :: Int)
    describe "bar" $ do
        it "id" $ property $
            \x -> x `shouldBe` (x :: Int)
```

This does not:

```
module ExampleSpec where

import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck

spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "foo" $ do
        it "id" $ property $
            \x -> f x `shouldBe` (x :: Int)
        where
            f = id
    describe "bar" $ do
        it "id" $ property $
            \x -> x `shouldBe` (x :: Int)
```

It fails with:

```
/mnt/c/haskell/chapter15/tests/ExampleSpec.hs:13:5: error: parse error on input ‘describe’
   |
13 |     describe "bar" $ do
   |     ^^^^^^^^
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of inherent limitation with `where`?

Comment: I should add I've tried playing around with `{}` and `;` to no avail

Comment: I love the way you use `where` as an expression. Many of us think `where` should be an expression and usable just like you did above. However, as the answers below explain, `where` is more restricted and can only come in particular places (ex. as part of a declaration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `where` clause can *only* be attached to a function or case binding, and must come after the right hand side body.

When the compiler sees `where`, it knows that the RHS of your `spec = ...` equation is over. Then it uses indentation to figure out how far the block of definitions inside the `where` extends (just the single `f = id` in this case). Following that the compiler is looking for the start of the next module-scope definition, but an indented `describe "bar" $ do` is not valid for the start of a definition, which is the error you get.

You cannot randomly insert a `where` clause into the middle of a function definition. It *only* can be used to add auxiliary bindings in scope over the whole RHS of a binding; it cannot be used to add local bindings in scope for an arbitrary sub-expression.

However there is `let ... in ...` for exactly that purpose. And since you're using `do` blocks under each `describe`, you can also use the `let` statement (using the remainder of the `do` block to delimit the scope of the local bindings, instead of the `in` part of the `let ... in ...` expression). So you can do this instead:

```
spec = do
    describe "foo" $ do
        let f = id
        it "id" $ property $
            \x -> f x `shouldBe` (x :: Int)
    describe "bar" $ do
        it "id" $ property $
            \x -> x `shouldBe` (x :: Int)
```

Comment: I did notice that without the `in` shadowing of assignments occurs for usage in the same indentation level.  Makes sense, just a note

Comment: @BenHeilman This is a syntactic issue and is not really related to semantics. Semantics describes the meaning of syntactically valid code, and the code in the question is not syntactically valid.

Comment: @BenHeilman I'm not 100% sure what you mean by that. Bindings introduced in a `let` **statement** (in a do block, no `in` keyword) scopes over the entire rest of the do block they occur in (so everything following that is part of a construct starting on the same indentation, yes). Bindings introduced by the `let ... in ...` **expression** are scoped over the expression in the `in ...` part (but `let ... in ...` expressions only use indentation for the bindings block, not the `in ...` part). Either of them will shadow bindings from enclosing scopes, as will any method of binding a name.

Answer (score 2):

This is a syntactic restriction in service of the scoping rules of a where block. Within a `where` block, values bound in a pattern match are in scope, and values defined in the `where` block are in scope for guards within that pattern match. As such, a `where` block must be attached to locations where a pattern match and guards at the very least could exist. This ends up being value declarations and branches of case expressions. In your second example you are trying to attach a `where` block to an arbitrary expression, which is just not what they're intended to do.